# c#.net Restful API Works on debug/release but not on IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have am creating a restful API application in c#.net. When I compile my application in debug or release mode through iisexpress. It works as expected. I can use fiddler and pass the corresponding arguments in the "GET" like the user credentials and it will connect and get a respond of 200 (http://localhost:49917/v2/Carriers). When I publish my application and deploy it in IIS (http://api.test1.net/v2/Carriers). IIS is install the same computer where I compile my application. Then, I use fiddler and pass the argument necessary I get a respond of 503. I am not sure why is not working. My application pools is the following setting: 
.Net CLR Version: v4.0
Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated
Identity: LocalService (I have tried also ApplicationPoolIdentity)

When I publish my application I use the following publish method: "File System".

I have added the IP Address and the host name in the Host file (windows/system32/drivers/etc/). I am not sure why is not working.

What makes visual studio different in debug/release mode to work as expected from publish version?

Comment: Unfortunately a 503 error can be the result of many problems, you should enable IIS logging to see what the underlying root cause is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503 - the error means the server received the request but cannot handle it. Is the site started in IIS? Is there some other error? Check the event viewer and IIS logs in case there's info there. It seems unrelated to Visual Studio itself, more to do with IIS. Perhaps the IIS site is not mapped to that host or IP, or something. Could be a number of issues, unfortunately, so more info is required.

Comment: "*What makes visual studio different in debug/release mode to work as expected from publish version?*": the host; IIS is configured incorrectly. Start at the beginning: make sure correct .net frameworks are installed and all the necessary IIS features are enabled.

Comment: Is the webservice asp.net core? If so, check if the IIS Hosting Bundle for .net core is installed.

Comment: 1) I will try enabling IIS logs (Matthew), 2) (Stefan) I have enabled all the windows features related to "internet information services" Do you recommend a specific windows feature? 3) (Haldo) This application is an asp.net web api (VS2013) with a .NET framework 4.5. This is not an asp.net core.

Comment: Can you try [Failed-Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let you guys know that I did what you guys recommended and I figure the answer. I need to add a new user in the SQL Server Database.

"Accessing Database under IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
As we are using ASP.NET v4.0 App Pool make sure IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 is added to your Database Server -> Security -> Logins."

After I added this new user "IIS APPPOOL\api.test1.net" the api get request with fiddler works as expected with a 200 respond. "api.test1.net" is the name of my application pool in IIS.

Thank you for all your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found a Microsoft Article about this exact issue being caused by IIS 7.5 or higher and User Instance has been turned on for the SQL Server.

To fix this log into the IIS Server and go to the APP Pool settings for the API not working e.g. DefaultAppPool V4.0 - Under Advanced settings locate the section Process Model - Set the Load User Profile = true.

Microsoft help page : [Application Pool Identities and SQL Server Express](https://web.archive.org/web/20231010201548/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities-and-sql-server-express)

Update to the web.config was also required to add the  <remove name="webDAVModule:/>  as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" 
         path="*."
         verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Project.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```